# When does Python reset the thread count?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Assume a main program that creates 5 threads, one at a time:

*main.py*

```py
import threading
import time
from camera import Camera  # this class inherits threading.Thread

# Initialize lock
lock = threading.RLock()

for i in range(5):

    # Initialize camera threads
    thread_1 = Camera(lock)

    # Start videorecording
    thread_1.start()

    time.sleep(100)

    # Signal thread to finish
    thread_1.stop()

    # Wait for thread to finish
    thread_1.join()

    del thread_1
```

When the thread is started, it prints its name with `threading.currentThread().getName()`, resulting in the following output:

```
Thread-1
Thread-2
Thread-3
Thread-4
Thread-5
```

How come the name of the thread keeps increasing? I assumed that Python would reset the Thread-*xxx* number after deleting each thread after its execution with `del thread_1`.

This was the expected output:

```
Thread-1
Thread-1
Thread-1
Thread-1
Thread-1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can assume that the number at the end of the name corresponds to the number of currently active threads:

> *name* is the thread name. By default, a unique name is constructed of the form “Thread-N” where N is a small decimal number.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

For example, the following code doesn't even start the threads, but immediately deletes them:

```py
import threading
for _ in range(3):
    t = threading.Thread()
    print(t.name)
    del t
```

And still prints:

```
Thread-1
Thread-2
Thread-3
```

**Update:** Just had a look at the implementation of `threading.py` at CPython, where `Thread.__init__` calls `_newname` if no name is given.

```py
# Helper to generate new thread names
_counter = _count().__next__
_counter() # Consume 0 so first non-main thread has id 1.
def _newname(template="Thread-%d"):
    return template % _counter()
```

Source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d0acdfcf345b44b01e59f3623dcdab6279de686a/Lib/threading.py#L738

That counter will just keep increasing.

Comment: Thank you! Your update with the details of how the threading module deals with incrementing the thread name made it very clear to me :)